# Remove address tags and split

Tags: python

Given the following string:

```
<address>
        113 N Michigan St<br/>Chicago, IL 60661
</address>
```

How could one split it so that it returns two strings:

```
113 N Michigan St
Chicago, IL 60661
```

And, in the case where you have a string like this:

```
<address>
     113 n. Michigan St
</address>
```

It will return:

```
['113 n. Michigan St','']
```

Or similarly for this string:

```
<address>
     Chicago, IL 60661
</address>
```

It will return the following:

```
['','Chicago, IL 60661']
```

I have tried putting something together, but am quite terrible at regular expressions:

```
re.search(r'<address>\.(.*?)</address>', *above string here*).group(1)
```

Comment: lol your edit makes it a much trickier problem, you'll need actual business logic code not just regex

Comment: Hah yeah, crap :( I just noticed when I ran the code that I forgot to include the significant detail

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `regex` to parse html data. Use something specially designed for this like `BeautifulSoup`

```
>>> text = """<address>
...         113 N Michigan St<br/>Chicago, IL 60661
... </address>"""
>>> 
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
>>> 
>>> [addr.strip() for tag in soup.find_all('address') for addr in tag.strings]
['113 N Michigan St', 'Chicago, IL 60661']
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regular expressions:

```
s = '''<address>
        113 N Michigan St<br/>Chicago, IL 60661
</address>'''
strs = s[s.index('<address>')+len('<address>'):s.index('</address>')].strip().split('<br/>')
#['113 N Michigan St', 'Chicago, IL 60661']
```

Answer (score 1):

If `s` is your address block string:

```
parts = [re.sub(r'\s*\n\s*', '', p) for p in re.split(r'<br/?>', re.sub(r'</?address>', '', s))]
```